# Calcular tempo de importação de DUMP

Tags: oracle, oracle11c

Gostaria de saber, se possível, teria como calcular aproximadamento o tempo de importação de um [Dump](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dump_de_banco_de_dados).

Poderia ser algo considerando os seguintes itens:

- Tamanho do DUMP em GB.
- Quantidade de Tabelas.
- Quantidade de Registros e(ou) linhas/colunas por tabela.
- Quantidade de Objetos, como Triggers, Functions, Procedures, etc.
- Alguma forma de calcular a eficiência computacional de processamento do computador?

> Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit
>   NOARCHIVELOG

O computador que utilizo para realizar os IMP:

> Windows 7 Professional 64bits
>   4gb RAM
>   i3 3.3GHz

OBS.: Utilizando o comando `IMP` e/ou `IMPDB`.

Comment: Não sei se te ajuda, mas olha aqui: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_monitor_data_pump_import_job.htm

Comment: @Diego, no link resolve com IMPDP preciso com IMP também, mas muuuuito obrigado!!!

Comment: Pergunta: você está planejando alguma migração de banco ou apenas quer estimar um tempo de restauração para um possível crash? Ou nenhuma destas?  Qual é sua versão de banco? Standard ou EE? está com archivelog ativo? S.O?

Comment: @Diego, alterei a pergunta com as respostas.

Comment: Se eu utilizar como efeito de comparação um dump de 1gb e gastar 2h para importação então fazer regra de três para descobrir o tempo de um dump de 5 gb dando 10 horas de importação? kkk

Comment: @Diego, posta sua resposta com DataPump que eu marco como respondida.

Comment: Creio que isso vai te ajudar: [Data PUMP Import](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_monitor_data_pump_import_job.htm)

Comment: @Diego coloca uma resposta completa, com explicação do link (e porque o conteúdo do link responde) à pergunta que vou também votar `+1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possivel monitorar o tempo usando essa query:

```html
col table_name format a30

select substr(sql_text, instr(sql_text,'"')+1, 
               instr(sql_text,'"', 1, 2)-instr(sql_text,'"')-1) 
          table_name, 
       rows_processed, 
       round((sysdate
              - to_date(first_load_time,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))
             *24*60, 1) minutes, 
       trunc(rows_processed / 
                ((sysdate-to_date(first_load_time,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))
             *24*60)) rows_per_min 
from 
   v$sqlarea 
where 
  upper(sql_text) like 'INSERT % INTO "%' 
  and 
  command_type = 2 
  and 
  open_versions > 0;
select 
   sid, 
   serial#
from 
   v$session s, 
   dba_datapump_sessions d
where 
   s.saddr = d.saddr;

select 
   sid, 
   serial#, 
   sofar, 
   totalwork
from 
   v$session_longops;
```

Fontes: [Aqui](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_monitor_data_pump_import_job.htm) e [aqui](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_monitor_data_pump_export_expdp.htm)

Comment: Essa resposta serve somente para IMPDB, ou seja, DataPump. Utilizando o comando IMP não seria possivel